# Tooltip using title attribute without js?

Tags: html, css

I'm searching a long time after another solution for making tooltip from `title=""` attribute on `:hover` selection.

I hope to find a way for using `title=""` attribute and change my `content:""` property dynamically.

```css
* {
   -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
   font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

div {
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background: rgb(25, 181, 206);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  border: none;
  font-size: 1em;
}
    
button::after {
  content: "I'm a css tooltip!"; /* <= dynamically title content */
  z-index: -999;
  position: absolute;
  top: 110%;
  left: 0;
  width: 90%;
  padding: 5px 5%;
  font-size: 70%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgb(21, 151, 171);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg) rotateY(20deg) rotateZ(20deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(180deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotateX(180deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateX(180deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  transform: rotateX(180deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0%;
  transform-origin: 100% 0%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: cubic-bezier(0.3, 0.05, 0.4, 1.7) .55s;
  -webkit-transition: cubic-bezier(0.3, 0.05, 0.4, 1.7) .55s;
  -moz-transition: cubic-bezier(0.3, 0.05, 0.4, 1.7) .55s;
  -ms-transition: cubic-bezier(0.3, 0.05, 0.4, 1.7) .55s;
  -o-transition: cubic-bezier(0.3, 0.05, 0.4, 1.7) .55s;
}
    
button:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button title="I'm a css tooltip1!">button</button>
  <button title="I'm a css tooltip2!">button</button>
  <button title="I'm a css tooltip3!">button</button>
</div>
```

[**Demo**](https://fiddle.jshell.net/zeevkatz/xx6szcha/)

There is a way to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `data-` attribute if you need custom attributes, and without `data-` if you need non custom attributes (eg title)

```css
* {
   -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
   font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

div {
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background: rgb(25, 181, 206);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  border: none;
  font-size: 1em;
}
    
button::after {
  content: attr(data-title); /* <= dynamically title content */
  z-index: -999;
  position: absolute;
  top: 110%;
  left: 0;
  width: 90%;
  padding: 5px 5%;
  font-size: 70%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgb(21, 151, 171);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg) rotateY(20deg) rotateZ(20deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(180deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotateX(180deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateX(180deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  transform: rotateX(180deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0%;
  transform-origin: 100% 0%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: cubic-bezier(0.3, 0.05, 0.4, 1.7) .55s;
  -webkit-transition: cubic-bezier(0.3, 0.05, 0.4, 1.7) .55s;
  -moz-transition: cubic-bezier(0.3, 0.05, 0.4, 1.7) .55s;
  -ms-transition: cubic-bezier(0.3, 0.05, 0.4, 1.7) .55s;
  -o-transition: cubic-bezier(0.3, 0.05, 0.4, 1.7) .55s;
}
    
button:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button data-title="I'm a css tooltip1!">button</button>
  <button data-title="I'm a css tooltip2!">button</button>
  <button data-title="I'm a css tooltip3!">button</button>
</div>
```

[Jsfiddle link](https://fiddle.jshell.net/xx6szcha/15/)

Comment: Interesting! can i change 'data-title' to 'title'? i need it for accessibility. and one more question, what about browser support?

Comment: You don’t need `data-`. Just use `title`.

Comment: @ZeevKatz Yes, you can. I include `data` to my answer as example, so you can include any custom attribute with `data-` prefix.

Answer (score -4):

I think there is a nice example of tooltips: [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips)

example:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Tooltip on left">Tooltip on left</button>
```